# Eclipse Pydev adding PYTHONPATH=../:. before running a pytest module

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, pydev, pytest, pythonpath

I am developing something in Python in Eclipse PyDev. Per the instructions from my assignment, I need to run this program like so:

```
PYTHONPATH=../:. python grade_analysis.py
```

However I am just running the program with the standard Run button and (no surprise) it's not working correctly. It is a unit test that claims it runs 0 tests.

Does anyone know how to run this specific file with that pythonpath in Eclipse PyDev? I've been playing with settings in the Run Configuration and no luck

Comment: maybe you could set the PYTHONPATH with hardcoded/absolute paths in your .bashrc or whatever, so Eclipse inherits from it. That would work (I don't know PyDev but there are probably better ways to set pythonpath when running)

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure those paths to be source folders inside of PyDev (a source folder is the folder that should be in the PYTHONPATH).

See: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html for details.